# AB (Apache benchmark) to the authenticate

Tags: performance, apache, benchmarking

I want to test the performance of my apache with AB (Apache Benchemark) with parameter authentication.
I followed this tutorial step
[Using Apache Benchmark (ab) on sites with authentication](http://makandracards.com/makandra/13757-using-apache-benchmark-ab-on-sites-with-authentication)
and when I execute the command

```
ab-c 1-n 1-C PHPSESSID = 65pnirttcbn0l6seutjkf28452 http://my-web-site
```

but authentication does not pass

```
testeur@ERP:~$ ab -c 1 -n 1 -C PHPSESSID=65pnirttcbn0l6seutjkf28452 http:my-web-site.com/mapviewimproved
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, `http://www.zeustech.net/`
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking my-web-site.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        algeotrack.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /my-page
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   0.627 seconds
Complete requests:      1
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      1
Total transferred:      335 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    1.59 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       627.320 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       627.320 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.52 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       36   36   0.0     36      36
Processing:   591  591   0.0    591     591
Waiting:      591  591   0.0    591     591
Total:        627  627   0.0    627     627
```

I note that the application is developed with Zend Framework 1

is that you can help me please

Answer (score 3):

You have to quote the cookie value:

```
 ab -c 1 -n 1 -C 'PHPSESSID=65pnirttcbn0l6seutjkf28452' http:my-web-site.com/mapviewimproved
```

see this other question as reference: [How do I pass a complex cookie to ab for testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047869/how-do-i-pass-a-complex-cookie-to-ab-for-testing)